# Custom tactics provided by libraries

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Is there a way to see all custom tactics provided by a library from inside Coq?
Searching for them using Search does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Print Ltac Signatures` command to list all tactics currently loaded, but there is no direct way to only list tactics from one library.